# How can I insert images on exported "excel.xls" from filemaker?

Tags: excel, filemaker

I currently have a FM Database (simple) where I need to export the records to a formatted excel worksheet.
Now, I alredy have the formatting done but there is one thing missing.
A LOGO.
Even though I can insert an image, it won't save it when the worksheet is closed and I need it to be there 24/7.
Is there any way to fix this?

I've alredy tried calling the image on my "Stylesheet.xml" file but keep getting an error since I don't know the images Type/Identifier.

Per example, for text I need to type "String". Numbers, "Number".

Don't have the code with me right now (left it at work) and left in a hurry.

I need the image to show 24/7.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to export the image in an Excel XML file or working in Excel, trying to insert an image? Also, you need to provide version and platform.

Comment: @AndreasT I'm trying to export in an Excel XML or XLS file. I'm using FileMaker Advanced Pro on Windows 10 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You're not saying anything about the version of FileMaker or Excel, but I'm assuming your target is Excel 2003 based on the XLS extension.

These are the only supported types of the Data element in the XML format for XLS: Number, String, Boolean, DateTime, Error.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa140066(v=office.10)#odc_xmlss_ss%3adata

You need to move to the newer XLSX format. There is a FileMaker plugin 360 Works Scribe that might be able to generate the XLSX file with images from FileMaker.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention the FM's version. I'm using FM 17 and Excel 2003.

Comment: Yes, I thought about moving to XLSX but that plugin is paid.

Comment: That's the only option I know of that might work, other than manually open the XLS file in Excel, insert the image and save the file in excel 2007 format (XLSX). I've seen VB script solutions around the web that can manipulate Excel cells this way, so you might have a look at that and then calling the script from FileMaker if you want it to be automated.

Comment: There is another option: export the data as the worksheet component of an .xslx file. Add the other components and zip the result. But this is a lot of work and the last part requires either a plugin (e.g. Base Elements) or OS-level scripting.